# Admin LTE in Blazor with buttons

Tags: blazor-server-side, adminlte

I have recently created a Blazor Server application and added the Admin LTE ui. Everything on the ui works as planned except the data grid with the buttons found here:
https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/iframe.html

In Blazor I have added all the js files and the stylesheets as per the downloaded page on github.
https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/releases/tag/v3.1.0

Here is the problem, when I load the page the buttons appear for a brief moment and then disappear again:

[image]

Not at all sure why this happens. When I click fast enough the buttons does work it just does not stay there